# JSON Polymorphic serialization in .NET7 Web API

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, system.text.json, .net-7.0

.NET7 Includes a lot of improvements for `System.Text.Json` serializer, one of which is polymorphic serialization of types using the new `[JsonPolymorphic]` attribute. I am trying to use it in my Asp.Net web API, however it doesn't seem to serialize the type discriminator despite the fact that the model is properly setup.

It only happens when trying to send the objects over the wire, when using JsonSerializer, everything appears to be working well. For example:

```cs
// This is my data model
[JsonPolymorphic]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(SuccesfulResult), typeDiscriminator: "ok")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(ErrorResult), typeDiscriminator: "fail")]
public abstract record Result;
public record SuccesfulResult : Result;
public record ErrorResult(string Error) : Result;
```

```cs
// Some test code that actually works
var testData = new Result[]
{
    new SuccesfulResult(),
    new ErrorResult("Whoops...")
};

var serialized = JsonSerializer.SerializeToDocument(testData);
// Serialized string looks like this:
// [{ "$type": "ok" }, { "$type": "fail", "error": "Whoops..." }]
// So type discriminators are in place and all is well
var deserialized = serialized.Deserialize<IEnumerable<Result>>()!;

// This assertion passes succesfully!
// We deserialized a collection polymorphically and didn't lose any type information.
testData.ShouldDeepEqual(deserialized);
```

```cs
// However, when sending the object as a response in an API, the AspNet serializer
// seems to be ignoring the attributes:

[HttpGet("ok")]
public Result GetSuccesfulResult() => new SuccesfulResult();

[HttpGet("fail")]
public Result GetFailResult() => new ErrorResult("Whoops...");
```

Neither of these responses are annotated with a type discriminator
and my strongly-typed clients can't deserialize the results into a proper hierarchy.

```http
GET /api/ok HTTP/1.1
# =>
# ACTUAL: {}
# EXPECTED: { "$type": "ok" }
```

```http
GET /api/fail HTTP/1.1
# =>
# ACTUAL: { "error": "Whoops..." }
# EXPECTED: { "$type": "fail", "error": "Whoops..." }
```

Am I missing some sort of API configuration that would make controllers serialize results in a polymorphic manner?

Comment: I am not sure, but it almost feels like ASP.NET is passing the object instance to be serialized _together_ with its type object to the serializer. Because that is a quirk of the current version System.Json.Text (see here for a demo of how the type meta data is not generated when the type object is passed to the serializier: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rXdlJw). Not sure how to fix that, though (i am not very knowledgeable about asp.net stuff...) :-(

Comment: Could this be a bug in the asp net then? I would have to browse through their sources to see how exactly they do serialization on their side

Comment: Or alternatively, it might mean that some annotation would be needed on the derived types as well

Comment: Yeah, it seems you found a fix (at least with the simple example case): https://dotnetfiddle.net/Pw6wBi Not sure if this is a happy accident or intended behavior (because the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0) does not seem to mention this case), but it works...

Comment: It kind of seems unintentional considering JsonPolymorphic attribute throws an exception when it doesn’t have any known derived type attributes, but I’ll try

Comment: Like in my dotnetfiddle example i linked to in my last comment, you need to put appropriate \[JsonDerivedType\] attributes on _both_ the base and the derived types to make both JsonSerializer.Serialize calls in my code example work...

Comment: In my case it is including the $type on the json, and deserializing to the correct type, but all the properties are null.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Specifying `[JsonDerivedType(...)]` on individual subclasses **and** on the base type seems to resolve an issue but barely seems intentional. This possibly might be fixed in future releases.

```cs
[JsonPolymorphic]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(SuccesfulResult), typeDiscriminator: "ok")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(ErrorResult), typeDiscriminator: "fail")]
public abstract record Result;

[JsonDerivedType(typeof(SuccesfulResult), typeDiscriminator: "ok")]
public record SuccesfulResult : Result;

[JsonDerivedType(typeof(ErrorResult), typeDiscriminator: "fail")]
public record ErrorResult(string Error) : Result;
```

Comment: That is a nice workaround, also remember that if you've customized the TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName using the JsonPolymorphic attibute you need to add it to the subclasses as well.

Comment: Having the same problem and the workaround works. I don't need the JsonPolymorphicAttribute though

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the base type when serializing for it to work without annotating every derived type with `[JsonDerivedType(...)]`

```
var serialized = JsonSerializer.SerializeToDocument<Result[]>(testData);
```

**Update:**

This is a known bug in ASP.NET Core tracked [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45548) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/77532). (Doesn't affect IEnumerable results)

The link has a workaround by a .NET Team member in this [comment](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/77532#issuecomment-1300541631) using a custom resolver as follows

```
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { TypeInfoResolver = new InheritedPolymorphismResolver() };
    JsonSerializer.Serialize(new Derived(), options); // {"$type":"derived","Y":0,"X":0}
    
    [JsonDerivedType(typeof(Base), typeDiscriminator: "base")]
    [JsonDerivedType(typeof(Derived), typeDiscriminator: "derived")]
    public class Base
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Derived : Base
    {
        public int Y { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class InheritedPolymorphismResolver : DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
    {
        public override JsonTypeInfo GetTypeInfo(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            JsonTypeInfo typeInfo = base.GetTypeInfo(type, options);
    
            // Only handles class hierarchies -- interface hierarchies left out intentionally here
            if (!type.IsSealed && typeInfo.PolymorphismOptions is null && type.BaseType != null)
            {
                // recursively resolve metadata for the base type and extract any derived type declarations that overlap with the current type
                JsonPolymorphismOptions? basePolymorphismOptions = GetTypeInfo(type.BaseType, options).PolymorphismOptions;
                if (basePolymorphismOptions != null)
                {
                    foreach (JsonDerivedType derivedType in basePolymorphismOptions.DerivedTypes)
                    {
                        if (type.IsAssignableFrom(derivedType.DerivedType))
                        {
                            typeInfo.PolymorphismOptions ??= new()
                            {
                                IgnoreUnrecognizedTypeDiscriminators = basePolymorphismOptions.IgnoreUnrecognizedTypeDiscriminators,
                                TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = basePolymorphismOptions.TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName,
                                UnknownDerivedTypeHandling = basePolymorphismOptions.UnknownDerivedTypeHandling,
                            };
    
                            typeInfo.PolymorphismOptions.DerivedTypes.Add(derivedType);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    
            return typeInfo;
        }
    }
```

It should be fixed in .NET 8

Comment: The problem is not with explicit deserialization/deserialization, but with ASP.NET's own model binding mechanism.

Comment: @MarengoHue you are correct, check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. All the proper polymorphic attributes were in place for the base class. I ended up working around it by explicitly invoking the serializer myself `Results.Content(JsonSerializer.Serialize(data, opts.Value), "application/json")`

Note: It worked as expected and serialized the `$type` for `IEnumerable<BaseType>` via `Results.Ok`

Comment: this is not ideal as it requires you to do a lot of boilerplate and also limits the API's ability to respond with a different content type (e.g. if the caller requests XML)

Comment: Boilerplate seems subjective here. You're okay with the `[JsonDerivedType]` boilerplate but not this? To your second point, you're the API author - you can decide what to return and when. Using this technique doesn't make it any more restrictive to send a different content type as needed.

Comment: As an API author I want my api to be honouring standard HTTP headers such as ‘Accept’. ASP.NETs infrastructure already handles this for me in most scenarios. In your method I would have to handle it explicitly.