# In ASP.NET core 7 JsonDerivedType doesn't seem to work for single object

Tags: asp.net-core, polymorphism, .net-7.0

We are using JsonDerivedType to support polymorphic types in ASP.NET core 7 endpoints. It works fine when querying a collection. We get a collection of different types each serialized to JSON objects with all properties and the $type discriminator.

When querying a single object it gets serialized to JSON with all its proprieties but does  not include the $type discriminator. So when sending the object back with updates it does not get deserialized to the correct type. We get the base type instead.

With these types:

```
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(MyTypeFirst), typeDiscriminator: "First")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(MyTypeSecond), typeDiscriminator: "Second")]
public class MyTypeBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyTypeFirst : MyTypeBase
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public class MyTypeSecond : MyTypeBase
{
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
}
```

And this controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyTypeController : Controller
{
    private List<MyTypeBase> myTypes = new()
    {
        new MyTypeFirst { Id = 1, Name = "First Type", FirstName = "First Name"},
        new MyTypeSecond { Id = 2, Name = "Second Type", SecondName = "Seconde Name"}
    };

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public MyTypeBase Get(int id)
    {
        return myTypes.FirstOrDefault(mt => mt.Id == id);
    }

    [HttpGet()]
    public IReadOnlyList<MyTypeBase> Get()
    {
        return myTypes;
    }

}
```

This query:

```
https://localhost:7129/api/MyType
```

Returns this which is correct:

```
[
  {
    "$type": "First",
    "firstName": "First Name",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "First Type"
  },
  {
    "$type": "Second",
    "secondName": "Seconde Name",
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Second Type"
  }
]
```

But this query:

```
https://localhost:7129/api/MyType/1
```

Returns this which is missing the discriminator:

```
{
  "firstName": "First Name",
  "id": 1,
  "name": "First Type"
}
```

That seem odd to me. To support polymorphic types for round trips you would always need the discriminator included even when querying a single object.

Is this the normal behavior? Am I missing a setting?

**update**
[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74848162/7218808) [marengohue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2396264/marengohue) resloved the problems by adding `JsonDerivedType` to each of the derived types. It does solve the problem but that is not how Microsoft describes the setup [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0#serialize-properties-of-derived-classes) and it seem redundant. So, is there a better way?

Comment: I don't find any other method except the link you provided.